# Set A Variable in Session When The Submit Button is clicked in Struts

Tags: session, struts2

I have a iterator which goes through a list and create their name and for each of them a button. I want when the user click the button put the same name that has been clicked in the session
This is my code

```
        <s:iterator value="packageCities" status="portStatus">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <s:property value="cityName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <s:if test="%{status == 0}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <s:submit method="open"  align="center" value="" cssStyle="background: transparent url(image/open.png) no-repeat center top; border: 0px; width: 150px; height: 30px;" >
                            <s:set name="button" value="cityName" scope="session"/>
                        </s:submit>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
```

But The problem is it only sets the last property , And it doesn't set it when user clicked the button! so it like when its creating the button it is putting the cityName in the session! But I only want to put different thing in session by clicking different buttons!
Can Any Body Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Submit the value along with the form (a hidden field may be used for this purpose). Then set the session variable in the action class.
2. Make a synchronous ajax request to set the session value onclick of the submit buttons.

As [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524382/456135) mentioned when the jsp is loaded the values are already set you cannot change them from client side.

**EDIT**

Ok, as you requested, here is a basic idea of the first method. The idea is to set the id of submit buttons with the respective `cityName` and then onclick of button call a javascript function to set a hidden field's value with the clicked button's id (i.e. its `cityName`)

```
<s:form>
<s:hidden id="value_to_submit" name="value_to_submit"/>
<s:iterator value="packageCities" status="portStatus"><s:form>
    ....
                <s:if test="%{status == 0}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <s:submit id="%{cityName}" onclick="set_hidden_value(this.id)" method="open"  align="center" value="" cssStyle="background: transparent url(image/open.png) no-repeat center top; border: 0px; width: 150px; height: 30px;" >
                            </s:submit>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </s:if>

    </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function set_hidden_value(myvalue){
document.getElementById("value_to_submit").value=myvalue;
}
```

Now you can capture the value of the variable `value_to_submit` in your action class and set the session variable there.

Comment: Can you Please Give me an example on the first solution?

Comment: the thing I want to do is like to pass an argument with the submit button! because I'm creating the button in a for loop so i want different things happen for each of them! if you know another way please let me know!

Comment: Or Maybe You know a way to set a variable in javascript so i can call the javascript method in onclick and the get the variable in method that i have in the java class!

Comment: Thank you very much! That's awesome! {you put the name of the javascript function wrong fix it if you want if anybody else come and see this topic} Thanx Again1

Comment: Always happy to help. Also i fixed the typo you mentioned,tnx

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

One, the name is always the same, so you're always setting the same property.

Two, and more important, the JSP has executed all the JSP tags by the time it gets to the browser--this is not how you set a session variable on a button click.

The session variable needs to be set in the action handling the submit.

Comment: the cityName is different values of the list Packagecities ! its in the class that i have! but how should I set the session when the button is clicked!?