# creating a Session variable in onclick() event of PHP submit button

Tags: php, onclick, session-variables

I created a form and have gone through a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524310/set-a-variable-in-session-when-the-submit-button-is-clicked-in-struts) on Stackoverflow as well, relating to this area of sending a variable from one page to another.

I need to pass this value $id=$row['id']; to the next page, but if I store it in the session variable (inside the while lopp) then it stored only the last item and not the current value.

```
<form name="send" method="POST" action="got.php">
 <hidden id="value" name="value"/>
//<input type="text" id="value">
//<input type="hidden" name="myVariable" value="'.  htmlentities("myVariable").'">;
<input type=submit name=submit value="submit"  onclick="<?php session_start(); $_SESSION(this.id) ?>">
</form>
```

The full code is given below,

```
echo "<form name=payment action='properties_details.php'>";
echo "Results <br>";
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo " <table border=3 cell padding=1> <tr> <td> ";

$id=$row['id'];
$pid=$row['pref'];
//And the remaining values as well      

//<input type="hidden" name="myVariable" value="'.  htmlentities($pid).'">;
//<input type="hidden" name="myVariable" value="'.  $pid.'">;

echo "<p>Property ID &nbsp".$pid;
echo "<br> <p> Name &nbsp";
echo $row["name"];
echo "<br>  Properties &nbsp";
echo $row["catergory"];
// And printing the remaining values

echo "<input type=submit name=btnbuy value=Details> ";
```

Comment: What's this? `<input type=submit name=submit value="submit"  onclick="<?php session_start(); $_SESSION(this.id) ?>">` You seem to mix JS with PHP.

Comment: I tried doing it separately as well (javascript between head tags) but it didnt work

Comment: You should do it separately. It won't work because you were handling it incorrectly.

Comment: but in javascript you cannot make SESSION variables, so then it would give the same result as now (last value in the loop)

Comment: PHP session variables are handled inside the PHP code, not in HTML or JS scripts.

Comment: ohh i thought he is asking something else.ok make AJAX call than

Comment: Suggestion: Read more about PHP sessions before you proceed, or this will give you a lot of headache and a mountain of problems.

Comment: First be clear with server script & client script... You cannot execute server script inside the client script until or unless you make a server request... Better use AJAX for your solution

Comment: +1 to remove the downvote. The asker is a noob.

Answer (score 2):

- You were not handling PHP sessions correctly.
- Your onclick event
  should fire a JS code, not PHP code.
- PHP is a back-end scripting
  language, and JS is a front-end scripting language. They don't mix.

**Suggestion**: Before you proceed with coding, read more about html, forms, passing form variables to php, php sessions etc.

**Resources/Tutorials:**

- Tutorial for handling PHP sessions:
  http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm
- Passing form variables to PHP Tutorial:
  http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson11.php

Comment: I tried the javascript technique however the variable is empty in the next page

Comment: @Yoosuf show me the exact technique you made. Let us discuss this in chat.

Comment: @Yoosuf go here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13922/php-session-handling-with-yoosuf

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your $id=$row['id'] on another page using query string easily.

on your button pass query string like this.

href="page_name.php?xyz=value you want to pass on second page"

1.here page_name.php is the page name on which you want to pass the value of $row['id'];

2.xyz is the query string name with the help of this we can get id on page_name.php

on page_name.php get query string as:

$id=$_GET["xyz"];

here xyz is a query string variable passed on button click

After that you can easily use this $row ['id'] on second page by using $id variable.

like this

echo $id;

Comment: on submit button pass query string as <button type="button" href="secon_page.php?xyz<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">